# Can functors have multiple member functions?

Tags: c++

I had the idea of creating a way to count how many times a given operator (the + in this case) was used.

So I came up with the following functor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T> class plus {
    private:
        unsigned int num_of_calls;
    public:
        plus(): num_of_calls(0) {};

        T operator() (const T& x, const T& y){
            num_of_calls++;
            return x+y;
        }

        unsigned int get_num_of_calls(){
            return num_of_calls;
        }
};


int main () {
  int first[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int second[]={10,20,30,40,50};
  int results[5];

  plus<int> plus_operator;

  std::transform (first, first+5, second, results, plus_operator);
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) std::cout << results[i] << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl<<std::endl;

  std::cout<< "Number of calls: "<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<plus_operator.get_num_of_calls()<<std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

It adds the elements together nicely, but when I call the `get_num_of_calls()` function, it returns `0` just as a newly initialized functor should. But if I print the actual value of `num_of_calls` inside the `()` operator then it works fine.

What causes this behaviour? Can functors have additional member functions besides the `()` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calling `std::transform`, you are passing a copy of your object. You should pass a reference with `std::ref`, or use a lambda instead:

```
std::transform (first, first+5, second, results, [&](const auto lhs, const auto rhs) { 
    plus_operator(lhs, rhs); 
});
```

Or:

```
std::transform (first, first+5, second, results, std::ref(plus_operator));
```